# Woocommerce: I can’t set “Geolocation (with page caching support)

Tags: woocommerce, geolocation

In Woocommerce/settings/general I set "Default customer location" to "Geolocate".

Our geolocation is working weird, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

I want to try the option “Geolocation (with page caching support)” but I can not save this settings. MaxMind Integration is active.

Take a look a this 30 seconds video to watch what I mean: https://www.loom.com/share/ef4f76fe50574deaac2cf87a38e0e30f

Also a capture: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/36682234?key=a0f39ce43feededae8808b4677495e1e

What is causing this issue?

Thanks.